# Ускорение слайдинга

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Есть 3 картинки, на каждой слоган.
С помощью `ViewPagerIndocator` переключаемся между картинками. Т.е. на экране 1 картинка + текст + индикатор. При свайпе в бок выползает другая картинка с текстом.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы текст "уезжал" быстрее, чем картинка?

**upd:** На картинке "надпись" должна "уезжать" по свайпу, быстрее чем сама картинка.

Как в приложении `SoundCloud`:

[image]

Comment: Мне кажется, вам нужен здесь ViewFlipper. Разруливается с помощью анимаций. Но, конечно, с прокруткой придется распрощаться.

Comment: Боюсь, что не все понимаю, как в SounCloud. Но если я правильно понял, то можно сделать с помощью двух  ViewPager'в.

Comment: @Andreich добавил картинку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну это же паралакс. 
Надо было искать по нему. Я вот [нашел](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/ParallaxPager).
Вот [тут](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2014/01/02/using-parallax-for-fun-and-profit/) еще.

Comment: Вот Спасибо!